# MySQL, select from different table... IF

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a small trouble since it was a long time ago i studies databases and querys.

For example i'll have two tables for cd:s, one with data and one with alternative translations.
In the CD-table i have the original language, and it looks something like this

```
Table for CDs (cds):
id  |  name  | language
-----------------------
1   |  aaa   | en
2   |  bbb   | en
3   |  ccc   | fi

Table for languages (languages):
cd_id | language | name
-----------------------
1     | fi       | AAA
1     | de       | AAACHTUNG
3     | en       | CCC
```

Now, i want to get all these cd:s in for example german, if there's no translation made i want it to be in the original language...

Edit:
German = de

Since there's only one german translation (on CD #1) i want cd 2 & 3 in thier original names.. English and finnish in this case...

How can i do this?

Edit 2:
In this case when i ask for 'de' i would get:

```
AAACHTUNG
bbb
ccc
```

If i ask for 'en' i would get

```
aaa
bbb
CCC
```

And so on...

Comment: which if the following is german? and what happens if there are multiple langauges like for `ID = 1`?

Comment: yea, i edited. German = 'de' :)
and if there's many translations i want it to be the requested or the original...

Comment: can you also add you desired result?

Comment: It seems like your table structure is making it more complicated than it needs to be.  You probably shouldn't have the language column in your main CD table.  Move all language info to the Language table and add a column to designate which language is the original language for that CD.

Comment: @N1tr0 - Agreed, although I think you meant `name`, not language there.  Moving the localization to a dedicated table would help his design some.

Comment: Yea, this is not what i use, this is just for simplyfying the problem... :)

Comment: But i could use the tip any way... unfortnatly the tables does not have any realations... but if i create a new cd, and the ID is AUTO_INCREMENT, how can i pass that generated ID to the 'languages' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f328a/1/0)):

```
select coalesce(l.name, c.name)
from cds c
left join languages l on l.cd_id = c.id
                         and l.language = 'de';
```

Comment: Well, yes... It works perfekt in fiddle, but i don't get the translated version... only the original... and can't figure out why... But at least it feels like i'm really close now... :)

Comment: What do you mean with "only the original"? In sqlfiddle there's your first expected result.

Comment: "original" = cds table. on my project... but yes, it works in fiddle and is coorect.

Comment: yea exactly, started a new thread inspired by the comment about having all the names in one table...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313746/mysql-passing-a-auto-increment-to-another-table

Answer (score 0):

```
select cds.id, IFNULL(languages.name, cds.name) as name
from cds 
left join languages on cds.id = languages.cd_id and languages.language = 'de'
```