# MySQL, passing a AUTO_INCREMENT to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Since the other one was answered correctly and i got a new idea for solving my problem (that's not really like the case under) i start a new thread.

Same example, the cds.id is AUTO_INCREMENT and these two tables does not really have any relations, is there any way to post the generated id to the languages table?

```
Table for CDs (cds):
id | type
-----------------------
1  | CD  
2  | LP  
3  | CD  

Table for names:
cd_id | language | name
-----------------------
1     | fi       | AAA
1     | de       | AAACHTUNG
3     | en       | CCC
```

Now the SELECT would be really simlple and the structure is better,
If i now have e form for creating a CD, like

```
<input... > = the name -> 'best of XX'
<select...> = language -> 'en'
<select...> = type     -> 'CD'
```

and i do a post, how can i do a multiple insert?
The insert to these tables should be...

```
INSERT INTO cds ('', 'CD');
INSERT INTO languages ('*the generated id in table above*', 'en', 'best of XX');
```

Comment: What technology is communicating with MySQL? PHP?

Comment: yea... you're thinking insert -> select -> insert on the result from the select? in this case i have nothing to ask for, there are many 'CD':s... i could get the lasted created one, but this could be bad if two people creates something at the same time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) which returns the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for the most recent `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO languages (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'en', 'best of XX');
```

Most languages have a wrapper for this function. For example, in PHP it's [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: yes. this could work. and i think it will in this case... but if two users posts at the same time they could get the same last created number... just thinking if there's a better way for doing that, like having just one query for both tables and not 2.

Comment: if a post is made into another table at the same time and it has a AUTO_INCREMENT, would'nt there be a risk that it will get this id and there by link to the wrong id? "how big is the chance?" - if something CAN go wrong, it WILL. that's my experience ;)

Comment: I understand the concern. However, there are measures to prevent this. Review the links in my answer. I wouldn't be worried. Especially when the query is run in sequence. However, you could always use a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

Comment: @gubbfett - the LAST_INSERT_ID returns the last auto increment value for the most recent insert *for the current connection*.  So if each user on the site has their own database connection (which they should) then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
INSERT INTO languages (last_insert_id(), 'en', 'best of XX');
```

[Last_Insert_Id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) gets the last auto increment value of an auto generated id column